# jquery - Check if input text field is filled, save to var

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, string-length

I have a form with radiobuttons and textfields.

I can store number of checked radiobuttons into a variable like this:

```
var $answeredRadiobuttons = $questions.find("input:radio:checked").length;
```

How can I store number of textfields that has text within them?

```
var $answeredTextfields = $questions.find("input:text").length;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var $answeredTextfields = $questions.find("input:text").filter(function(){
    return this.value !== "";
}).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
var $answeredTextfields = $("input").filter(function() {
  return $(this).val() != "";
}).length;
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TpM6u/)**